# Is it possible to share public code through heroku like I can with Github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, language-agnostic, repository, github, heroku

On Github, I can send a page link with a file of code. Does Heroku have the same functionality, or do I have to have them clone the project and added as a collaborator to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a very good article that explains how to do this:

http://www.watchtowerinnovations.com/blog/2010/02/08/collaboration-for-heroku-users/

Basically, you can use GitHub for your repository.  You start there, then add Heroku as another remote location you can push to.  So when you push to github, nothing happens.  That's good, because you don't always want to deploy new changes.  But when you push to heroku, your app will be redeployed.

Comment: Wow can't thank you enough again Jaime. I crown and dub thee Lord of the Answer.

Comment: haha, glad I could help :) I actually felt a little lazy pointing you to an article instead of including all the examples in my answer.